# suspension of the torus

Tags: general-topology

The suspension of $S^n$ is $S^{n+1}$. What about the suspension of $T^n$? Is it just $S^2\times T^{n-1}$? I'm having a hard time visualizing even the first non-trivial case $\Sigma T^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cartesian product of two manifolds is a manifold, so $S^2 \times T^{n-1}$ is a manifold. The suspension of the torus, however, is not. In fact, the suspension of a manifold is almost never a manifold – the only counterexample is the sphere (proof: a it's a standard exercise that $\tilde{H_n}(X)=\tilde{H}_{n+1}(\Sigma X)$ where $\Sigma X$ is the suspension. See Hatcher, section 2.1, Exercise 20. Now use Poincaré duality.)

A good way to imagine the suspension $\Sigma T^2$ is to imagine $T^2$ as a flat square, where you know the edges are pairwise identified but you don't actually fold the square to affect the identification. The suspension is now obvious: build two pyramids with the square as their base, one above and one below, to obtain a kind of octahedron.

*Now* identify the edges. Of course, you need to identify them all the way up and down.

[image: Suspended torus]

(Image [source](https://www.him.uni-bonn.de/homepages/prof-dr-matthias-kreck/the-stratifold-page/))

The tips of the suspension are singularities. They don't have neighborhoods homeomorphic to Euclidean space; their links are tori, not spheres.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to work this out algebraically in the homotopy category of pointed space because there is a formula for this.  We use $\cong$ to denote homotopy equivalence.

Let $X$ be a topological space with a base $x$.  Then the suspension operation $S(X)$ turns $\{x\} \times I$ into an interval.  In order to obtain a space with a base point, we contract this $\{x\} \times I$ into a point and obtain $\Sigma(X)$, the reduced suspension of $X$.  Suppose $X,Y$ are spaces with base points $x,y$, respectively.  Then we can join $X, Y$ at the base points and obtain a new pointed space $X \vee Y$.  Then we have a general formula:

$\Sigma(X \times Y) \cong \Sigma(X) \vee \Sigma(Y) \vee \Sigma(X \wedge Y)$.

The $\wedge$ is the smash product which is a bit complicated, but we have the relation:

$X \wedge S^1 \cong \Sigma(X).$

In our particular case we can get rid of it using induction.

To do this, substituting $T^1 = S^1$ for $X$ and $Y$, we get

$\Sigma(T^2) = \Sigma(T \times T) \cong \Sigma(S^1) \vee \Sigma(S^1) \vee \Sigma(S^1 \wedge S^1) \cong S^2 \vee S^2 \vee S^3.$

These and together with the fact that
$\Sigma(S^n) \cong S^{n+1}$ will give you $\Sigma(T^n)$ by induction on $n$.